# Redux devtools missing from window object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, redux

Today I was working on one of my projects and a little bit into it(after making some changes) I started to get this error:

[image]

Redux Configuration:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import { getFirebase} from 'react-redux-firebase';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const initializeState = (state = {}) => {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    state,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase, getFirestore})),
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__()
    )
  )
};

export default initializeState;
```

After playing around with my redux configuration i decided to check the production application that is hosted with firebase and that hasnt had a code change in about two days and the same error was present. So i was able to rule out any of the code changes I had made locally.

After that I removed this line from the compose function:
`window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__()` and it worked.

Im not really sure how to figure out where this issue is coming from. When I check the properties and methods on the window object (in chrome) and scroll to where it looks like those redux properties might be they arent there:
[image]

Anyone have any clue on the issue behind this? Did those items get removed from the window object (that seems unlikely). Is this an issue with my version of chrome? Something else perhaps? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Open issue: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/320, you need to change that line to make sure that wither or not the client has the redux dev browser extension installed you pass in a valid value (function?). Redux itself expects a function but your line will pass in `undefined` if the extension isnt installed

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thank you! Ill try and implement that. Can you think of any reason why it would have worked fine for the past three or so months but now its suddenly and issue?

Comment: only thing i can think of is you had the dev tools extension installed during that time, and disabled/removed it some time later.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your help i got it working.